# Why illegal start of declaration in Scala?

Tags: scala

For the following code:

```
package FileOperations
import java.net.URL

object FileOperations {
    def processWindowsPath(p: String): String {
        "file:///" + p.replaceAll("\\", "/")
    }
}
```

Compiler gives an error:

```
> scalac FileOperations.scala
FileOperations.scala:6: error: illegal start of declaration
        "file:///" + p.replaceAll("\\", "/")
```

Why? How to fix?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You're missing an = from the processWindowPath method declaration.

```
package FileOperations
import java.net.URL

object FileOperations {
    def processWindowsPath(p: String): String = {
        "file:///" + p.replaceAll("\\", "/")
    }
}
```

Comment: All scala tutorial listings are missing of that symbol http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaTutorial.pdf

Comment: Yup, there's a lot of code there that doesn't return a value. If the method returns a value, you need the = sign. Page 8 has the first example in the linked document.

Comment: Do these function return value? If they don't they're not supposed to use `=`.

Comment: Yes, only functions that doesn't return a value are without = sign in tutorial.

Comment: Is there a specific name that `=` is supposed to be called when used with `def`?

Answer (score 7):

```
object FileOperations {
  def processWindowsPath(p: String): String  = {
    "file:///" + p.replaceAll("\\", "/")
  }
}
```

There is a missing `=`. Methods in Scala are defined this way:

```
def methodName(arg1: Type1, arg2: Type2): ReturnType = // Method body
```